# mysqldump with utf8 can not export the right emojis string

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, emoji

I am using MySQL 5.5.29, utf8mb4 charset, there is a table user containing a field `nickname` with value hex `F09F988EF09F988E` that translates to the emojis .

Now open MySQL console, and execute:

---

```
set names utf8mb4;
select nickname, hex(nickname) from user;
```

---

```
nickname | hex(nickname)
---------+-----------------
    | F09F988EF09F988E
```

---

And then execute:

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8 -utest -ptest test_dev user > user.sql
```

Check the `user.sql` and find the nickname display `??` which hex string is 3f

So, how can mysqldump with UTF8 export the right emojis string?

---

btw, the database charset envionments configured as follow:
show variables like 'character_set_%':

```
'character_set_client', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_connection', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_database', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_filesystem', 'binary'
'character_set_results', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_server', 'utf8mb4'
'character_set_system', 'utf8'
'character_sets_dir', '/data/mysql/share/charsets/'
```

Comment: What happens when 1) You change the default character set to "--default-character-set=utf8mb4" 2) You export directly to a file e.g.
execute "mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -utest -ptest test_dev user -r user.sql"

Comment: Also, have you tried re-importing the data? It may just be that your editor is displaying the question marks as it doesn't have the correct characters available in it's font.

Answer (score 32):

Thanks Danack! 
 
Thru specifying `utf8mb4` charset and upgrading mysqldump version to 5.5.3+, mysqldump & mysql work well for 4 bytes emojis.

```
[tomcat@localhost ~]$ mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -utest -ptest test_dev user > user.sql
```

If it shows an error like:

```
mysqldump: Character set 'utf8mb4' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
```

check your `mysqldump` version (`mysqldump --version`)

```
[tomcat@localhost ~]$ mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.11 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

It works after upgrading mysqldump to 5.5.33.

```
[tomcat@localhost ~]$ mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.33, for Linux (x86_64)
```

Comment: related:  As of this date the export tool in MySql Workbench hardcodes the default-character-set option to utf8 ...*sigh*..

Comment: @BradKent Fun-Fact: It's thanks to MySQLWorkbench that I got aware of this solution at all haha. Worked like a charm with utf8mb4 :)

Answer (score 14):

It's true that you need to use `mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4` (notice the `--default-character-set` option) when exporting.

But then importing is still super tricky. I tried so many different approaches and had no success.

**Finally, I discovered that you need to create an `importer.sql` file like this:**

```
USE my_example_db_name;

# Select the right charset
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';

# Import from SQL file
SOURCE /somewhere/dump.sql;

# Disconnect from SQL server
EXIT
```

Then, to import, run this:

```
mysql -u my_user my_example_db_name < /somewhere/importer.sql
```

Thank you to https://korobochkin.wordpress.com/2017/02/25/import-and-export-wordpress-database-with-utf8mb4-charset/

Comment: --set-charset should have the same effect should it not?

Answer (score 2):

Was struggling with this for a while as well. The other solutions in this thread still caused `dump.sql` to still have multiple wrong characters for emojis.
Turns out, using `>` is not a safe way of exporting *(at least not on my machine, Windows 10)*. Using `-r dump.sql` instead of `> dump.sql` did the trick.

This command exports all the tables of the database:

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -h [host] -u [username] -p [database_name] --set-gtid-purged=OFF --port=3306 --protocol=tcp --skip-triggers -r dump.sql
```

Then for importing, first run this command:

```
mysql -h [host_name] -u [username] -p [database_name] --binary-mode -o
```

And then, when in mysql mode, type the following:

```
USE database_name;
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
SOURCE /dump.sql;
EXIT
```

Hope this helps others that had the same issue!