# How to preserve UTF8mb4 data with mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, utf8mb4

I'm using mysqldump to dump my database that contains UTF8MB4 columns with UTF8MB4 data. When I import this `.sql` file into a new database with UTF8MB4 support, all UTF8MB4 characters are converted into `????`. Anybody got a clue about how to make MySQL and import work with UTF8MB4?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216849/mysqldump-with-utf8-can-not-export-the-right-emojis-string

Comment: The Henridv answer is correct and should be accepted, but then importing is still tricky. What worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298202/470749

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should specify the character set with `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` option when using `mysqldump`.

```
$ mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -uusername -p database > dump.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

Since MySQL 8.0 [default charset for mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_default-character-set) is  **utf8mb4**, so the problem should not appear anymore.

However in MySQL 5.7 [default charset for mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_default-character-set) is **utf8**, so there you should explicitly change it as in Henridv answer (`--default-character-set=utf8mb4`).