# MySQL utf8mb4, Errors when saving Emojis

Tags: mysql, emoji, utf8mb4

I try to save names from users from a service in my MySQL database. Those names can contain emojis like  (just for examples)

After searching a little bit I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814293/how-to-insert-utf-8-mb4-characteremoji-in-ios5-in-mysql) linking to this [tutorial](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4). I followed the steps and it looks like everything is configured properly.

I have a Database (charset and collation set to utf8mb4 (_unicode_ci)), a Table called TestTable, also configured this way, as well as a "Text" column, configured this way (VARCHAR(191) utf8mb4_unicode_ci).

When I try to save emojis I get an error:

```
Example of error for shortcake ():
    Warning: #1300 Invalid utf8 character string: 'F09F8D'
    Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB0' for column 'Text' at row 1
```

The only Emoji that I was able to save properly was the sun ☀️

Though I didn't try all of them to be honest.

Is there something I'm missing in the configuration?

**Please note:** All tests of saving didn't involve a client side. I use phpmyadmin to manually change the values and save the data. So the proper configuration of the client side is something that I will take care of **after** the server properly saves emojis.

**Another Sidenote**: Currently, when saving emojis I either get the error like above, or get no error and the data of `Username`  will be stored as `Username ????`. Error or no error depends on the way I save. When creating/saving via SQL Statement I save with question marks, when editing inline I save with question marks, when editing using the edit button I get the error.

thank you

**EDIT 1:**
Alright so I think I found out the problem, but not the solution.
It looks like the Database specific variables didn't change properly.

When I'm logged in as root on my server and read out the variables (global):
Query used: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';`

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For my Database (in phpmyadmin, the same query) it looks like the following:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8               |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

How can I adjust these settings on the specific database?
Also even though I have the first shown settings as default, when creating a new database I get the second one as settings.

**Edit 2:**

Here is my `my.cnf` file:

```
[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld_safe]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
user=mysql
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port=3306
basedir=/usr
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
tmpdir=/tmp
lc-messages-dir=/usr/share/mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
max_connections=200
max_user_connections=30
wait_timeout=30
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=5
innodb_file_per_table
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: it's a phpmyadmin problem, try other mysql client.

Comment: I don't think it's a phpmyadmin problem. As you can see in Edit1 I think it's some misconfiguration between conf/default variables/parameters and those on the database. Even though when creating a new database.

Comment: What is `$cfg["DefaultCharset"]` in your PMA configuration?

Comment: I didn't find `$cfg["DefaultCharset"]`. I looked it up in `etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. Not in there.

Comment: @jsxqf Hi there, after a while and redoing the whole "tutorial" I realized that it acutally was a mysql problem. The session variables were different than the global variables. A new connection, which is happening when using my api, uses the global variables and works :).

So actually, if you provide a full answer, I'll accept it and you'll get the bounty.

Also, on top of that, I'd appreciate if you also could state how I can reset phpmyadmins session variables. I didn't get this to work. They still are set wrong.

Comment: Did you try setting `$cfg["DefaultCharset"]` to a reasonable value like `utf8mb4` in your config?

Comment: Hello. I am having the same problem. What was in the end the thing that made it works for you?

Comment: Hi @johnnyfittizio, I'm currently rerunning through this problem xD. But as far as I remember, the solution was at one point the right configuration in the database itself, and then the right configuration of the client. All in all, running exactly, step by step, through the tutorial I linked in the beginning solved my issue. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have already tried that :) Anyway i will look it again. Let's see..

Comment: The always helpful internet says PMA has a setting `$cfg["DefaultCharset"]` but I don't see it in the docs.

Comment: There's `$cfg['DefaultConnectionCollation']`, however in current versions of PMA (v4.7). Defaults to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: It took me a long time to find this trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298202/470749

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`character_set_client`, `_connection`, and `_results` must all be `utf8mb4` for that shortcake to be eatable.

Something, somewhere, is setting a subset of those individually.  Rummage through my.cnf and phpmyadmin's settings -- something is not setting all three.

If `SET NAMES utf8mb4` is executed, all three set correctly.

The sun shone because it is only 3-bytes - `E2 98 80`; utf8 is sufficient for 3-byte utf8 encodings of Unicode characters.

Comment: Alright, I think this gets me closer. Thank you. I edited my question and added the my.cnf. Maybe you can see something in there?

Comment: The connection needs to have `utf8mb4`.  If you can't find where to do that, then execute `SET NAMES utf8mb4`.

Comment: This is a nice explanation on what also went wrong. But in addition I had to check the session and the global variables. Realizing PHPMyadmins Session variables were still wrong and the error was occuring for the admin board only.

Comment: Thank you. `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'");` that's right ;)

Comment: Oh, I missed one -- A shortcake is big enough for 4 bytes.

Comment: @luky - Start a new Question; supply details.  Review [_this_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) to see if it provides clues.

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8mb4` before the `INSERT` statement did the trick for me. Thank you all!

Answer (score 11):

For me, it turned out that the problem lied in mysql client.

mysql client updates `my.cnf`'s char setting on a server, and resulted in unintended character setting.

So, What I needed to do is just to add `character-set-client-handshake = FALSE`. 
It disables client setting from disturbing my char setting.

`my.cnf` would be like this.

```
[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8):

It is likely that your service/application is connecting with "utf8" instead of "utf8mb4" for the client character set. That's up to the client application.

For a PHP application see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

For a Python application see https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL#example or http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#mysql-unicode

Also, check that your columns really are utf8mb4. One direct way is like this:

```
mysql> SELECT character_set_name FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`  WHERE table_name = "user"   AND column_name = "displayname";
+--------------------+
| character_set_name |
+--------------------+
| utf8mb4            |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Symfony 5 answer

*Although this is not what was asked, people can land up here after searching the web for the same problem in Symfony.*

### 1. Configure MySQL properly

☝️ See (and upvote if helpful) top answers here.

### 2. Change your Doctrine configuration

> /config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        charset: utf8mb4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud of this answer, because it uses brute-force to clean the input.  It's brutal, but it works

```
function cleanWord($string, $debug = false) {
    $new_string = "";

    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {
        $letter = substr($string, $i, 1);
        if ($debug) {
            echo "Letter: " . $letter . "<BR>";
            echo "Code: " . ord($letter) . "<BR><BR>";
        }
        $blnSkip = false;
        if (ord($letter)=="146") {
            $letter = "&acute;";
            $blnSkip = true;
        }
        if (ord($letter)=="233") {
            $letter = "&eacute;";
            $blnSkip = true;
        }
        if (ord($letter)=="147" || ord($letter)=="148") {
            $letter = "&quot;";
            $blnSkip = true;
        }
        if (ord($letter)=="151") {
            $letter = "&#8211;";
            $blnSkip = true;
        }
        if ($blnSkip) {
            $new_string .= $letter;
            break;
        }

        if (ord($letter) > 127) {
            $letter = "&#0" . ord($letter) . ";";
        }

        $new_string .= $letter;
    }
    if ($new_string!="") {
        $string = $new_string;
    }
    //optional
    $string = str_replace("\r\n", "<BR>", $string);

    return $string;
}

//clean up the input
$message = cleanWord($message);

//now you can insert it as part of SQL statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_message (`message`)
VALUES ('" . addslashes($message) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

> ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` `column_name`
>   VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL
>   DEFAULT NULL;

example query :

```
ALTER TABLE `reactions` CHANGE `emoji` `emoji` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

[image]

after that , successful able to store emoji in table :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding

```
init_connect = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

to all of your your db-servers' my.cnf-s.

(still, clients can (so will) overrule it)

Answer (score 0):

I was importing data via command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...);
```

This didnt work for me:

SET NAMES utf8mb4;

I had to add the CHARACTER SET to make it working:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
'E:\\wamp\\tmp\\customer.csv' INTO TABLE `customer`
CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**Note, the target column must be also utf8mb4 not utf8, or the import will save (without errors thought) the question marks like "?????".**

Answer (score 0):

For `codeigniter` user, ensure your character set and collate setting in `database.php` is set properly, which is worked for me.

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8mb4';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```