# Saving emoji characters in mysql database

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, emoji, utf8mb4

I am trying to save some data on ***mysql*** database, input contains emoji characters like this :  '\U0001f60a\U0001f48d' and I'm getting this error:

```
1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x8A\\xF0\\x9F...' for column 'caption' at row 1"
```

I searched over net and read a lot of answers include these:
[MySQL utf8mb4, Errors when saving Emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis) or [MySQL utf8mb4, Errors when saving Emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis) or https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#character-sets or http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0080__Table/charactersetsystem.htm but nothing worked !!

I have different problems:

here is mydb info:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8               |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8_general_ci    |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried to change `character_set_server` value to `utf8mb4` by

```
mysql>SET character_set_server = utf8mb4
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But when restart `mysqld` everything revert !

I don't have any `/etc/my.cnf`  file in also, and I edited `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file instead.

What should I do?
How can I save emoji file in my database?

Comment: Well, yes, these settings revert. You need to set your ***connection encoding*** whenever you connect to the database as a matter of course. How exactly are you trying to insert what value exactly?

Comment: I'm developing a Django app and using python `django.db.backends.mysql` as engine to connect to MySQL server.

Comment: Could you be able to find a solution?

Comment: Actually I could not edit exiting db, but when I create a new with utf8mb4 collation everything workes fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st or 2nd line in source code (to have literals in the code utf8-encoded: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Your columns/tables need to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`

The python package "MySQL-python" version needs to be at least 1.2.5 in order to handle utf8mb4.

`self.query('SET NAMES utf8mb4')` may be necessary.

Django needs `client_encoding: 'UTF8'` -- I don't know if that should be 'utf8mb4`.

References:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18392
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: Warning. This will cause an error on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813689/cant-initialize-character-set-utf8mb4-with-windows-mysql-python