# Why my mysql Database nothingness in '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/'

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

When I use slqalchemy to connect to the mysql database, I get an error and it shows that I can't load uft8mb4. I have the answer that I want to modify the file '/user/share/mysql/charsets'. I found that I don't have this folder. I guess because When someone else installed mysql, the default location of mysql was changed.

I have modified '/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf'
The default encoding in the file.
Then restart the service, but still can't

```py
  File "/usr/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 115, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 435, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 221, in __init__
    self.set_character_set(charset)
  File "/usr/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 312, in set_character_set
    super(Connection, self).set_character_set(charset)
OperationalError: (2019, "Can't initialize character set utf8mb4 (path: /usr/share/mysql/charsets/)")
```

Comment: I want to modify '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/' but I can't find it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813689/cant-initialize-character-set-utf8mb4-with-windows-mysql-python