# Not able to insert emojis in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I was getting an error on inserting emoji through my android app in mysql db that :

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8D\xF0\x9F...' for column 'question_text' at row 1

so i searched for it and found out that i had to Change the character set and collation properties of the databases, tables, and columns to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8.
Well i thought of applying to just one column first so i executed the query:

> ALTER TABLE question MODIFY `question_text` varchar(100)
>   CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

But got the same error , than i thought of applying to the entire database so i executed the query:

> ALTER DATABASE my_database CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

but still getting the same error . Can someone explain to me what i could be missing?

Comment: Note that changing the default characterset on the database does not have any affect on existing tables or columns.

Comment: so how do i solve the problem then??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL utf8mb4, Errors when saving Emojis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis)

Comment: no it's not because i have set to utf8mb4 collation but still no effect