# Python3+Django1.10+mysqlclient1.3.9: cannot save emoji characters

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python, emoji

I got the error below in django when saving a field with emoji character in the admin panel.

> OperationalError at /admin/core/message/add/
>      (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x9E \xF0...' for column 'name' at row 1")

I'm sure the database is ready for `utf8mb4`, because I can write/read these emoji character in `phpmyadmin`.

More, the saved emoji character displayed correctly in `phpmyadmin` but displays `???` in django output.

And in my another django project, the emoji plays well, till I just cannot find the difference between the two environment.

So what can be the problem when I save the same thing using python?

The problem is under django framework, so I want a solution that make django work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL utf8mb4, Errors when saving Emojis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `DATABASE` section in the `settings.py` with *OPTIONS - charset* solves this issue:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myproject',
        'HOST': 'mysql',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'OPTIONS': {
            # !!!!!! THIS MATTERS !!!!!!
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        }
    },  
}
```

See documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#charset