# Trying to save special characters in MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have a string that looks like this `Use O Mozilla Que Não Trava! Testei!  $vip ou $apoio`

When I try to save it to my database with `...SET description = %s...` and `cursor.execute(sql, description)` it gives me an error

> Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x94\xB4Us...' for column 'description' ...

Assuming this is an ASCII symbol, I tried `description.decode('ascii')` but this leads to

> 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

How can I determine what encoding it is and how could I store anything like that to the database? The database is utf-8 encoded if that is important.

I am using Python3 and PyMySQL.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure the table column has correct character set setting.  If it is "latin1" you will not be able to store content that contains Unicode characters.

You can use following query to determine the column character set:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database_name' AND TABLE_NAME='your_table_name' AND COLUMN_NAME='description'
```

Following Mysql document [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html) if you want to change column character set.

Also, you need to make sure character set is properly configured for Mysql connection.  Quoted from Mysql doc:

> Character set issues affect not only data storage, but also
>   communication between client programs and the MySQL server. If you
>   want the client program to communicate with the server using a
>   character set different from the default, you'll need to indicate
>   which one. For example, to use the utf8 Unicode character set, issue
>   this statement after connecting to the server:
>
> ```
> SET NAMES 'utf8';
> ```

Once character set setting is correct, you will be able to execute your sql statement.  There is no need to encode / decode in Python side.  That is used for different purposes.

Comment: The first query gives `utf8` I init with pyMysql with `connect = pymysql.connect(host=constants.HOST,
                              user=constants.USERNAME,
                              password=constants.PASSWORD,
                              db=constants.DATABASE,
                              charset='utf8',
                              port=constants.PORT,
                              cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)` So there should not be an issue actually?

Comment: @PrimuS Just noticed there's an emoji. You need utf8mb4 for column character set. utf8 is not enough.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis