# myrocks (mariadb + rocksdb) php charset

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, rocksdb

There are already plenty of posts about choosing the right charset for mysql, but it's again a different (and very frustrating) story for the rocksdb engine.

Firstly, I decided to use utf8-binary as charset (latin1, utf8-bin and binary are supported by myrocks) because my data may contain special chars and I want to be on the save side.

Furthermore, I am using PHP and PDO for loading data into mysql and the connection looks like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
```

So I set the charset to utf8 (I also tried to use `utf8_bin`, but this is not supported by PDO). Although, I am able to insert some rows, sometimes I get errors like the following one:

> Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x87\xA8\xF0\x9F...' for column 'column_name'

But what's the error now? This hex sequence encodes a unicode-smily (a regional indicator symbol letter c + regional indicator symbol letter n). Seems for me like valid utf8 and mysql as well as php are configured to use it.

Comment: you may need to update your post to include the full query and values being passed. You can also try using a prepared statement if you haven't already. The question's unclear.

Comment: the problem is that it only happens infrequently and so it is not that easy to reproduce it. But I think, that the error message is already quite good, because I know that I am not able to store unicode smileys. I read somewhere that utf8 for mysql might be the problem, because it does not handle multi-byte chars properly and utf8mb4 is better, but rocksdb does not support utf8mb4 :/

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/39463134/ --- https://stackoverflow.com/q/7814293/ --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through --- https://stackoverflow.com/q/35125933/ to name a few.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for your effort, but as I already mentioned: utf8mb4 is not supported by rocksdb (at least I was not able to find it in the documentation), but it's the solution in all your posts...

Comment: You're welcome. I unfortunately don't know about rocksdb, so I won't be of any help there, sorry. I wish you well in finding the solution, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta have `utf8mb4`, not MySQL's subset `utf8`.

needs a 4-byte UTF-8 encoding, hex `F09F87A8`.

If rocksdb does not support it, then abandon either such characters, or rocksdb.  Change the charset in the PDO call, and on the columns that need it.