# 4 bytes emojis being saved inappropriately in MYSQL ignoring caracter set and Ok in google datastore

Tags: mysql, node.js

After reading [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4) tutorial on how to change mysql data structure to support four bytes emojis and this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis), I've set the following:

- node server receive the emoticon as a surrogate pair, like `String.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) and string.charCodeAt(1).toString(16) : d83d, de01,` which is the surrogate pair for `UTF16: U+1F601`.
- I changed the column of my table to `text varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL`
- For every transaction with emoticons, I run `conn.query('set character set utf8mb4')`. This set prevent me from having an exception. [EDIT] After this, command, if I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'` I got:

> 

```
  {Variable_name: "character_set_client", Value: "utf8mb4"} 
>         {Variable_name: "character_set_connection", Value: "utf8"} 
>         {Variable_name: "character_set_database", Value: "utf8"} 
>         {Variable_name: "character_set_filesystem", Value: "binary"} 
>         {Variable_name: "character_set_results", Value: "utf8mb4"} 
>         {Variable_name: "character_set_server", Value: "utf8"} 
>         {Variable_name: "character_set_system", Value: "utf8"} 
>         {Variable_name: "character_sets_dir", Value: "/usr/share/mysql/charsets/"}
```

But the result is that all emoticon are always saved as `'?'`, with the possible exception of three bytes emoticons in the 3rd line.

```
select text, hex(text) from table_text;
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| text                          | hex(text)                                                  |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| ?                             | 3F                                                         |
| Eita ?     ?                  | 45697461203F20202020203F20                                 |
| 1                             | 31                                                         |
| ? ??☺️??                      | 3F203F3FE298BAEFB88F3F3F                                   |
| ???????                       | 3F3F3F3F3F3F3F                                             |
| ???????   Crazy Stuff ??????? | 3F3F3F3F3F3F3F2020204372617A79205374756666203F3F3F3F3F3F3F |
| Crazy Stuff ???????           | 4372617A79205374756666203F3F3F3F3F3F3F                     |
+-------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[EDIT] So I found the problem. For some reason, if you only run `set character set utf8mb4` is not enough as it only changes `character_set_client`. To set `character_set_client` and `character_set_connection`, you must run `'SET NAMES utf8mb4'`

Comment: Generally it's a good idea to answer your own question if you solve your problem, then accept the answer. That way somebody else may be able to find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem. For some reason, if you only run `set character set utf8mb4` is not enough as it only changes character_set_client. To set `character_set_client` and `character_set_connection`, you must run

```
'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
```

before run the statement. So:

```
conn.query('SET NAMES utf8mb4');
conn.query('Your statement inserting/updating emojis')
```