# Minimal setup for MariaDB to handle Emojis

Tags: unicode, mariadb, utf8mb4

I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/35189650/4534 but still I get `Error 1366: Incorrect string value`, when posting an emoji into "name":

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`) VALUES ('Foo bar ');
```

SQL setup is:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
CREATE DATABASE rest_api_example;
USE rest_api_example;
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL
);
```

[image: Database configuration]

I use the **mariadb** image to test the above sql via https://github.com/kaihendry/GoApiTutorial/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` in the failing case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I add `command: ['--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci']` to the `docker-compose.yml`

[image: utf8 in MySQL]

Once I've done this, Emoji characters appear to work. However I've since discovered I can set charset/collation in the database creation, for example:

```
 CREATE DATABASE rest_api_example character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And that works better and I don't have to fiddle with mysqld settings.