# How to insert hindi value of json object in SQL Table using java?

Tags: java, mysql

Am trying to insert the below query,

```
INSERT INTO form_attributes(FormAttributeTypeID,FormUUID,AttributeValue) VALUES(4,'becb4607-7f43-4b72-aa9e-60b378122716','[{"id":5,"language":"हिन्दी  (Hindi)","renderingOrder":"Left to right","iso":"hi","renderingCode":"LTR","lcid":"hi","flag":true,"default":true}]')
```

Comment: 1) are you facing any errors while inserting, can you post errors?
2) can you post the expected output?

Comment: SQL Error [1366] [HY000]: Incorrect string value: '\xE0\xA4\xB9\xE0\xA4\xBF...' for column 'AttributeValue' at row 1

Comment: check if this resolves your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis

Comment: I already checked this one. But I did not get my solution

Comment: Can you add the supporting java code and sql scripts?