# Is it possible to have emojis in mySQL table names?

Tags: mysql, emoji, utf8mb4, tablename

Let's say if I'm making a website where I let people using emojis in their username, and I will have a table for each user to store their info/profiles/etc.., and the name of will be the same as their username.

I have no problem storing emojis or any special character into a table as data.

The character set and collation are both set utf8mb4 for my database, and I also have "CHARSET=utf8mb4" statement in my php mysqli_query function when I create the tables, it worked perfect for all kind of symbols, Chinese Characters, Japanese characters, even when I try to have these special character as part of the table names, no problem.

However, when I try to have emojis as part of the table names, whether I rename or create a table, mysql gives me a “#1300 - Invalid utf8mb4 character string” error.

Is it not possible to have emoji in the table names? If it is possible, how to do it?

Comment: "_and I will have a table for each user to store their info/profiles/etc_" Bad database design

Comment: The question is: why? And why you are creating a table for each user?

Comment: ` I will have a table for each user`....no, obviously you'd never want to do that. Or need to. You'll just end up with hundreds of tables with the same design, same column names, and just one row in each. And they only differ by the table name. And you'll have to write horrible, vulnerable, clunky code to access them (regardless of emoji use). This should _obviously_ be a single "users" table, and then each user is recorded as a separate row in that table. Have you done any database design tutorials? Or even just a basic PHP & Mysql tutorial? You'd soon get the hang of the basic approach.

Comment: P.S. `these special character`...there's nothing "special" about UTF-8, as such.

Comment: @hassan For example, if it is a blog, and every user have multiple articles, the articles of each user is stored in one table under the user's username.

Comment: @ADyson It's not like only one row in each table. For example, if it is a blog, and every user have multiple articles, the articles of each user (writer) is stored in one table under the user's username. So each article is a row in their writer's table. If someone have 10 articles, that's gonna be 10 rows in his table.

Comment: Store articles in an `articles` (or so) table and relate it to the `user_id` (assuming you have a `users` table as ADyson suggested). Really, that is bad database design

Comment: *For example, if it is a blog, and every user have multiple articles, the articles of each user is stored in one table under the user's username.* Do you want to create separate table for each user's articles?? I agree - bad design. Study about normal forms .. at least something.

Comment: @brombeer Actually I'm not storing userid or any "only one piece" user data in the article table. It's like I have one `users` table, where I have `username` `password` `email` as 3 columns.  And then every user have their own table named after their username for storing their articles in the`articles` column.

Comment: You don't need that either. You need **one** `articles` table, with each row being an article entry, containing the content, and a column for the username of the person who created it. That column should be a foreign key back to the users table. Again...study relational database  design basics _before_ trying to design a database, otherwise, like now, you'll tie yourself in knots and create lots of avoidable problems

Comment: Honestly, you should really just lookup [Database Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL utf8mb4, Errors when saving Emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35125933/mysql-utf8mb4-errors-when-saving-emojis)

Comment: @icecub I have `mysqli_set_charset($db_connection,"utf8mb4");` in my code, which I guess does the same thing as what is suggested by the answer in the link you shared. I think it works for the entries in the tables but not for the table name itself. 

Maybe I just should redesign my database as many people suggested here, so I don't need to have emojis in my table names..

Comment: Yes, absolutely you should do that. Your table names and database design generally should be fixed, and not need to change unless you make an enhancement to the application. If you find yourself (for example) creating a new table because a new user joined the site, or because some new data was inserted by a user, then that's a big sign that the database design is flawed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked is no, you can't use emojis in table identifiers, at least not in current versions of MySQL (as of version 8.3).

```
mysql> create table `mytable` ( i int );
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                               |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1300 | Cannot convert string 'my\xF0\x9F\x98\x8A...' from utf8mb4 to utf8mb3 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| my?table       |
+----------------+
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html says:

> Permitted characters in quoted identifiers include the full Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP), except U+0000

The BMP is the subset of UTF-8 that corresponds to MySQL's utf8mb3 character set. The Supplemental Multilingual Plane (SMP) is the full range of UTF-8, which corresponds to MySQL's utf8mb4 character set.

Basically, as of MySQL 8.3, the information_schema tables still uses utf8mb3, which only supports the Basic Multilingual Plane. I expect this to change eventually, as they seem to be phasing out utf8mb3 in favor of utf8mb4, but it will be in some future version of MySQL.

Emojis are in the Supplemental Multilingual Plane.